# How to run Microsoft QDK from source

Tags: q#

What is the general procedure for building and including QDK source code in a C# host project?

Following [Develop with Q# and .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/quantum/quickstarts/install-cs?tabs=tabid-cmdline%2Ctabid-csharp) I have set up a C# host project which references a Q# library on linux. Everything works when using the pre-built QDK and including `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.Quantum.Sdk/0.12.20072031">` at the top of the Q# library .csproj file.

However, I need to modify code in the [qsharp-runtime](https://github.com/microsoft/qsharp-runtime), so I want to compile from source rather than the SDK. I can successfully build the source, but am unsure how to make it "available" to the C# project. Following the advice in this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56876281/building-and-modifying-q-libraries/56876865#56876865), I have included project references to all projects with the qsharp-runtime and package references to the qsharp-compilers in the Q# .csproj file:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <!--Reference to Q# Runtime Projects -->
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\..\qdk\qsharp-runtime\src\Simulation\Common\Microsoft.Quantum.Simulation.Common.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\..\qdk\qsharp-runtime\src\Simulation\Core\Microsoft.Quantum.Runtime.Core.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\..\qdk\qsharp-runtime\src\Simulation\CsharpGeneration\Microsoft.Quantum.CsharpGeneration.fsproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\..\qdk\qsharp-runtime\src\Simulation\EntryPointDriver\Microsoft.Quantum.EntryPointDriver.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\..\qdk\qsharp-runtime\src\Simulation\QCTraceSimulator\Microsoft.Quantum.Simulation.QCTraceSimulatorRuntime.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\..\qdk\qsharp-runtime\src\Simulation\QsharpCore\Microsoft.Quantum.QSharp.Core.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\..\qdk\qsharp-runtime\src\Simulation\RoslynWrapper\Microsoft.Quantum.RoslynWrapper.fsproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\..\qdk\qsharp-runtime\src\Simulation\Simulators\Microsoft.Quantum.Simulators.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <!--Reference to Q# compiler package -->
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Quantum.Compiler" Version="0.12.20072031" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Quantum.Standard" Version="0.12.20072031" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

However, this results in the C# host no longer recognizing the Q# namespace. If the Q# is moved directly into the C# project in Library.qs, and referenced with `<Compile Include="Library.qs"/>`, it can no longer compile. There appear to be missing pieces that I'm not getting with the package references. If I include both the package references and the QDK the collision causes a build failure.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the AdvntageBenchmark project we recently added to the repo:
https://github.com/microsoft/qsharp-runtime/tree/master/AdvantageBenchmark/privateBuild

In summary I would:

1. Keep using the Quantum.Sdk to compile Q# projects
2. Import the `Simulators.Dev.props` so it automatically adds all project references and required props

This is how the project looks like:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.Quantum.Sdk/0.12.20082705-beta">
  <!-- Add project references to Simulator and other required packages: -->
  <Import Project="..\..\src\Simulation\Common\Simulators.Dev.props" />

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <IncludeQsharpCorePackages>false</IncludeQsharpCorePackages> <!-- otherwise the standard library is included by the Sdk -->
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Thank you for you quick response. I am able to run the releaseBuild (after changing the lower case q and p in the project files), which does not contain the `<IncludeQsharpCorePackages>false</IncludeQsharpCorePackages>`. But when I run the privateBuild it produces errors such as "Quantum.qs(555,44): error CS0115: 'Advantage56.Body': no suitable method found to override". I get identical errors in my own projects when using this approach

Comment: Additionally, this appears to allow one to modify the simulator code? Is it also possible to use this approach to modify the Driver (eg, Driver.cs) code?